# Manipulating Pandas DataFrame with conditions and groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV0Xs.png)

I have the above DataFrame with hundreds of Instruments and different Dates. For each Instrument in every Date,

I wish to look for 2 rows of `RecordType=='TRADE'` (highlighted in yellow).

The first Trade type is right after the `RecordType=='Control'`, and

the second Trade type is 30 minutes after the first Trade, that is, the latest Trade within 30 minutes after the first trade.

In my example, 30 minutes after the first trade (9:59:47AM) should be 10:29:47AM, and if I convert the timestamp to Milliseconds (since midnight), it is 35987025 + (30mins * 60 * 1000) = 37787025. Therefore, the last Trade before 37787025 is at 37417668 Milliseconds, which is highlighted in yellow. Those Trades highlighted in red are NOT what I want.

May I know what is the best way to code this? I know I have to `groupby(['Instrument', 'Date'])` for the analysis. Thank you.

Comment: use snippets to put code, show what you have tried so far, and basically read how to write a question in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably useful for you to know that you can use `apply` together with `groupby`. This is not a tested solution, but a rough guide how to get there:

```py
def handle_single_group(df):
    trades = df[df.RecordType=='TRADE']
    first_trade = trades.iloc[0]

    latest_time_ok = first_trade['Time'] + timedelta(30)
    last_trade = trades[trades.Time <= latest_time_ok].iloc[-1]
    return pd.concat([first_trade, last_trade], axis=0)

df.groupby(['Instrument', 'Date']).apply(handle_single_group)
```

This assumes the trades are ordered by Time. You can also look into using `argmax` if that's not the case.